# Facebook SDK stops $stateChangeSuccess (ui router) to trigger in Angularjs Run

Tags: angularjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to inject Facebook SDK into my Angularjs app, so I it render the like box in the site.

Since is a simple implementation I don't want to use any directive. And I had read how to inject third party scripts in angular.

I tried doing this in the run

```
(function(d){
        var js, id='facebook-jssdk'; //ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); 
        js.id = id;
        js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }($document[0]))

$window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

    // Executed when the SDK is loaded
    $window.FB.init({ 
        appId: '119418904821152',
        version    : 'v2.4',
        xfbml: true 
    });

}
```

And it works, but since I'm using ui router, and I need to register some changes after the "section" change I'm using $stateChangeSuccess. Also needed to "re render" the social plugins when changing of "section".

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event){

        if($window.FB != undefined){
            $window.FB.XFBML.parse()
        }
        console.log('stateChangeSuccess')       
    })
```

So this never fires, I tried to check if something was wrong also with $stateChangeError, but nothing.

I noticed that if I comment the Facebook code, $stateChangeSuccess fired correctly.

So do you have any idea what could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

try something like `$viewContentLoaded` or invoking the facebook parse function in your controller instead of `$stateChangeSuccess`. what i think to be happening is your `xfbml` tags are not loaded yet for `FB.XFBML.parse()` to parse.

one issue i encountered was `$window.fbAsyncInit` not ready and would give me an error `init not called with valid version`. to remedy this i moved the sdk script load to the `$stateChangeSuccess` and just did a quick check to see if it was already loaded, if not then load it.

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
    if($window.FB){
        FB.XFBML.parse();
    }
});

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(){
    if(!$window.FB){
        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    }
});

$window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({ 
        // ...
    });
}
```